# Does referencing a public final static string of class A in class B increase the size of the compiled class B?

Tags: java

Assume the following classes:

```
class A {
  public static final String someString = "thisIsSomeString";

  // then potentially lots of non static members and functions.

}

class B {
  void foo1() {
    String someStringFromA = A.someString;
  }

  // OR

  void foo2() {
     String someStringFromA = "thisIsSomeString";
  }

}
```

Here, `b.foo` sould be either `foo1` or `foo2`. The benefit of `foo1` is straightforward: only a single place to define the string name, if we need to change it, just change it here. But I have been told that using `foo1` would "import" somehow the code of A into B, so that the compiled class B could be potentially much larger using `foo1` instead of `foo2`. Is this true? I assumed using `foo1` would be equivalent to a C #define.

Comment: have you tried compiling the code and looking at the .class files?

Comment: -1  I'm sorry, even if it somehow did increase the size, what are we talking about here, about 40 bytes?

Comment: 40 bytes could be a problem on embedded systems with low memory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually both will result in the constant being inlined in `B.class` so no difference. As very often, go for the more readable / maintainable option.

This is the bytcode I get:

```
void foo1();
  Code:
     0: ldc           #3                  // String thisIsSomeString
     2: astore_1
     3: return

void foo2();
  Code:
     0: ldc           #3                  // String thisIsSomeString
     2: astore_1
     3: return
```

Comment: that's what I was thinking. Thanks!